# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In my Worklight 6.1 application I am getting this error in LogCat:

> 01-06 12:27:53.205: E/Web Console(7304): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   call method 'split' of null at
>   file:///data/data/com.****/files/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:3320

and this file is not editable(to insert try catch), if I forcefully edit this then application takes update from server.

I am running my app on Android 2.3.10.

Comment: Explain in your question what you are doing in your app... are you using any frameworks? Is there any special code in your app? There is really nothing to investigate until you add more information.

Comment: I am using JsonStore feature and twitter plugin using inAppBrowser in my application.

Comment: And the error is coming from worklight.js file near line :3320 where $.cookie("header-value") method is used, and header-value is may be null. There should be some default value like $.cookie("header-value") || "";

Comment: Since you are not providing any code or your project; then create a small test case that reproduces the issue.